# Creation "Loading Screen" for Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I parse the .html page and take set of checkbox, than I add checkboxes to layout and setContentView(layout). But parsing is slow, and I want to create loading window during data is loading. I don't know how to do it, help me please. Thank you for, anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For that you can implement [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) ([Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html)), **implement `ProgressBar` inside the onPreExecute() method of AsyncTask**.

As i have marked it is known as Painless Threading as we developer need not to bother about to start/pause/stop the thread, it is managed by Android itself.

### Update:

You can also show ProgressDialog inside the onPreExecute() method and then hide the same in onPostExecute() method. For the same, i suggest you to go through this article, really helpful: https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/asynctasks-with-progressdialogs

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using a progress dialog. There is a tutorial on the Android Developers Website, and this is where It starts to explain:

> A ProgressDialog is an extension of the AlertDialog class that can
>   display a progress animation in the form of a spinning wheel, for a
>   task with progress that's undefined, or a progress bar, for a task
>   that has a defined progression. The dialog can also provide buttons,
>   such as one to cancel a download.

The Link is here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html